# Can't copy an audio file

Tags: java, file, audio, copy

Okay so I'm get an error with this method that uses Files.toCopy it says that the file is already being used.

Files.copy( tempClip.toPath(), wavFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );

This is the method that opens the file. It copies fine when I don't use this method it gives the error when I do use this method. current.track below references the wavFile above. I thought I closed everything using the file with audioStream.close() and audioClip.close().

```
if ( e.getSource() instanceof QuoteButton) {
        QuoteButton current = (QuoteButton)e.getSource();
        try {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(current.track);
            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            audioClip.open(audioStream);
            audioClip.start();

            audioClip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                @Override
                public void update(LineEvent event) {
                    if(event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP){
                        audioClip.close();
                    }
                }
            });
            audioStream.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You close the audioclip in a listener so it's not actually called until you get LineEvent.Type.STOP

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I had a privacy leak. Fixed it.